# Problems configuring ocaml setup in emacs

Tags: config

## Emacs question

this is my config for working in ocaml in emacs:

```
;; Ocaml

(use-package tuareg
  :ensure t
  )


(use-package merlin
  :ensure t
  :config
  (add-hook 'tuareg-mode-hook #'merlin-mode)
  (add-hook 'merlin-mode-hook #'company-mode)
  )

(use-package merlin-eldoc
  :ensure t
  :hook ((tuareg-mode) . merlin-eldoc-setup))


(use-package flycheck-ocaml
  :ensure t
  :config
  (flycheck-ocaml-setup))


(use-package ocamlformat
  :ensure t
  :custom (ocamlformat-enable 'enable-outside-detected-project)
  :hook (before-save . ocamlformat-before-save))


(require 'ocp-indent)
(add-hook 'tuareg-mode-hook 'ocp-setup-indent)


;; Ocaml end ================
```

when i press enter it is lagging before inserting a newline and also lagging when i inserting `|` (bar) in `match-with` cases

I have no idea, where to look. Please help

## Update: SOLVED

The problem was in `flycheck-ocaml` removing it solved the problem

Comment: I would start by commenting out all the `use-package` forms except for the first two and also commenting out the `ocp-indent` configuration and seeing if the "lag" persists. If not, uncomment the others one by one and test after each uncommenting to find out who the culprit is. If it "lags" even with just the first two active, then comment out the `merlin` one and try with just `tuareg`. Then open an issue with whatever package you find out is the culprit.

Comment: I did it as you said and discovered that the problem was in `flycheck-ocaml`. removing it solved the problem. thanks!